# how can I make sub-menu appears using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am desperately trying to make sub-menu appears under menu-item below when I hover a mouse.
I created color-change and underline when menu-item is hovered using css but have no idea how to make sub-menu appears under the menu-item. I have no knowledge related jquery so I googled some jquery effect but did not work either. 
Is there other way to make it appears without using jquery?

```css
<style>
.menu {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
.menu-item-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 550;
}
.menu-item-text:hover {
  content: '';
  color: red;
}
.menu-item-text:hover:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(15, 1, 1);
  margin-top: 19px;
}
.sub-menu1 {
  background: yellowgreen;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}
.sub-menu a:before {
  content: '☆';
  top: 2px;
}
.sub-menu a:hover:before, .sub-menu a:focus:before {
  content: '★';
} 
.navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu-act .menu-item-text  {
  color: red;
}
.sub-menu1 li, .sub-menu1 a {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class='menu-item' tabindex='0'>
             <span class="menu-item-text menu-act">About HTML</span>
            <ul class='sub-menu'>
                <li>
                 <a href="#">HTML Introduction</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Reference Introduction</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Examples</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JQuery to display a submenu on hover. You can do it with CSS.

```
.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {display: block;}
```

If there is more than one submenu then use id or different class names for them. So you can display the corresponding submenu under each menu.

```css
<style>
.menu {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
.menu-item-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 550;
}
.menu-item-text:hover {
  content: '';
  color: red;
}
.menu-item-text:hover:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(15, 1, 1);
  margin-top: 19px;
}
.sub-menu1 {
  background: yellowgreen;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}
.sub-menu a:before {
  content: '☆';
  top: 2px;
}
.sub-menu a:hover:before, .sub-menu a:focus:before {
  content: '★';
} 

.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {display: block;}

.navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu-act .menu-item-text  {
  color: red;
}
.sub-menu1 li, .sub-menu1 a {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class='menu-item' tabindex='0'>
             <span class="menu-item-text menu-act">About HTML</span>
            <ul class='sub-menu'>
                <li>
                 <a href="#">HTML Introduction</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Reference Introduction</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="#">Examples</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
</body>
```

With JQuery you can simulate this as follows:

```js
$(".menu-item").on("mouseover", function(){   //This will display the submenu on mouse hover.
$(".sub-menu").show();
});

$(".menu-item").on("mouseout", function(){ //This will hide the submenu when mouse leaves the menu item.
$(".sub-menu").hide();
});
```

```css
.menu {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
.menu-item-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 550;
}
.menu-item-text:hover {
  content: '';
  color: red;
}
.menu-item-text:hover:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(15, 1, 1);
  margin-top: 19px;
}
.sub-menu1 {
  background: yellowgreen;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}
.sub-menu a:before {
  content: '☆';
  top: 2px;
}
.sub-menu a:hover:before, .sub-menu a:focus:before {
  content: '★';
} 

.navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu-act .menu-item-text  {
  color: red;
}
.sub-menu1 li, .sub-menu1 a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class='menu-item' tabindex='0'>
                 <span class="menu-item-text menu-act">About HTML</span>
                <ul class='sub-menu'>
                    <li>
                     <a href="#">HTML Introduction</a>
                    </li>
                   <li>
                     <a href="#">Reference Introduction</a>
                    </li>
                   <li>
                     <a href="#">Examples</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
               </li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
    </body>
```

You can use *[mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)* and *[mouseout](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/#mouseout-handler) or [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)* events of jQuery.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a solution with JQuery too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `CSS` but you mention you want in `jquery` that's why I make it with `Jquery`.

I think you want like this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu-item-text').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').show();
  });
  $('.menu-item-text').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  margin-left: 220px;
}
.menu-item-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 550;
}
.menu-item-text:hover {
  content: '';
  color: red;
}
.menu-item-text:hover:after {
  content:'';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(15, 1, 1);
  margin-top: 19px;
}
.sub-menu1 {
  background: yellowgreen;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.sub-menu li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}
.sub-menu a:before {
  content: '☆';
  top: 2px;
}
.sub-menu a:hover:before, .sub-menu a:focus:before {
  content: '★';
} 
.navigation .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu-act .menu-item-text  {
  color: red;
}
.sub-menu1 li, .sub-menu1 a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class='menu-item' tabindex='0'>
         <span class="menu-item-text menu-act">About HTML</span>
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li>
             <a href="#">HTML Introduction</a>
            </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#">Reference Introduction</a>
            </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#">Examples</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
```